# Article inside of JomSocial

Tags: joomla-3.x, jomsocial

Is there any way, to show an Article inside of the jomsocial-component?
Maybe a faq-page or terms of service page?

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the JomSocial developers or posting on their forum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always override the jomsocial view where you want the article to display, and add a module position there, and then display a module there that shows your artile. Output overrides for jomsocial are slightly different than for other components, but it's explained [here](http://documentation.jomsocial.com/wiki/Customizing_Template), the most important part quoted below:

> Before you can start customizing, you will need to create an Override Folder for JomSocial Component.
>   It seems that there is a lot of confusion regarding what files will go where and how to setup the override folder properly, mostly because the folder structure differs, but if you go trough it once, you will see that this is no rocket science and not something that JomSocial invented. We are just using the things that are available in Joomla:
>
> The very important thing to understand is that Joomla Template Override can only override the current component or module output. What this means, is that if you select the default template in JomSocial Template Settings the override will override the default template. If you select any other template to be used as your JomSocial template, the override folder will override that one. Bottom line, the override folder always override the active component output and is located here:
>
> JOOMLA/templates/yourTemplateName/html/com_community
>
> If you dont have this folder, feel free to create it manually

Now, to load the module in the overridden template, do something like this:

```
<?php echo JHTML::_('content.prepare', '{loadposition position-2}'); ?>
```

wich will load modules in module position-2